# Incorporating SCSS and font files from node_modules into my Next.js / Tailwind project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sass, tailwind-css, node-modules

My team and I are working on a Next.js app that uses Tailwind CSS. This is our employer's first foray into Next.js and one of the first things we are doing with React in general. The company has a project built up called corporate-web-assets that contains font icons and scss styling unique for our company branding and such. We have incorporated it into Angular apps through node_modules in the past. I am trying to do that now with the Next.js app.

Here is the structure of corporate-web-assets in node_modules:

```
node_modules
    corporate-web-assets
        assets/live
            fonts
                Baloo
                    Baloo-Regular.tff (& .woff)
                Interstate
                    Interstate-Bold.eot
                    Interstate-Bold.tff
                    Interstate-Bold.woff
                    Interstate-Bold.woff2
                    (A bunch of other files for Light, Regular, etc)
                Our-Company-Icons.svg
                Our-Company-Icons.tff (& .woff)
            scss
                _oc_main.scss
                brand.scss
                button.scss
                (8 more .scss files)
        node_modules (yes, a node_modules within corporate-web-assets which is itself in a node_modules)
            ansi-regex
            chalk
            (bunch of other stuff)
        package.json
```

I have a next.config.js file in which I have tried to incorporate the fonts and styles. Here are the contents of my next.config.js file:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const path = require('path');

const nextConfig = {
    output: 'export',
    // Optional: Change the output directory `out` -> `dist`
    distDir: 'dist',

    sassOptions: {
      includePaths: [path.join('./node_modules/corporate-web-assets/assets/live', 'styles')]
    },

    images: {
        unoptimized: true
    },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

I also have a tailwind.config.css file, but I don't think the contents are relevant. If I'm wrong, tell me and I will post the contents.

Here is the postcss.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

my globals.css file starts as follows:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@import 'scss/_oc_main';

:root {
  --foreground-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --background-start-rgb: 214, 219, 220;
  --background-end-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
}
(rest of styling)
```

I added that import of _oc_main based on what had been added in the Angular project to its styles.scss file. That caused the following error message:

```
 ⨯ ./src/app/globals.css
Module not found: Can't resolve 'scss/_oc_main'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./src/app/globals.css
```

Can anyone help me understand what I need to do to get those font icons and scss styling from node_modules to work in my project?

Comment: We have a similar structure & use SaaS. We use turbo repo to manage, definitely worth looking into. We don't set the `saasOptions`. We [transpilePackages](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/transpilePackages) and it works as expected.

Comment: I'm looking into it, but I'm confused about what I'm reading. Can you give me more specific detail on how you're implementing it?

Comment: We follow the process exactly as shown in the linked example. The `transpilePackages` array is simply the name specified in our package.json for the packages that we intend to transpile into our Next.js app. We also add the name to our packages list e.g. `"@myPackage/shared": "workspace:*"` and run install `npm i`